# out of memory at line 5 in SSRS report on server

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, msbi

I have developed a SSRS report in which I have user three different select queries to create three different report and not a single parameter is used in any of these queries, only select statement like

```
select col1,col2,col3 from table_name;
```

There is one main report using these three reports as sub-reports. When I run the main report in local machine or development environment, it's working/running fine. I'm getting output but on the server, the main report is throwing a error like `OUT OF MEMORY AT LINE 5`.

I have tried everything I know and searched on net also; didn't get any solution for this issue. Does anybody know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried pointing to the live database from your development environment? Maybe the live server is running low on ram

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/18e4bd96-055a-4024-b188-84512e1fb7e3/system-out-of-memory-exception-in-ssrs

Comment: I've also seen this error when my server was running out of HDD (no room left for temp tables, etc)

Comment: yes i have checked but that is not a issue